# How to round off number at decimal places

Tags: javascript

44571.123 * 75.46 = 3363336.94158, But I want the value 3363336.942. So do i write code in java script

Comment: number.toFixed(numberOfDecimals)

Comment: `(44571.123 * 75.46).toFixed(3)`

Comment: There's a manual you can read -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function like so:

```
var sum = (44571.123 * 75.46);
var decimal = sum.toFixed(3);
```

with 3 being the number of decimal places that you want.